# Значение функции PosEx

Tags: delphi, строки

Есть список строк:

```
123456:Ответ
1234:Ответ-1008!
1234567:Ответ-232!
12345:Отв
```

Нужно исключить строки, в которых, если после знака : или ; - меньше чем 3 символа. И записать все строки в которых после знака : или ; - символов больше чем 3.

В данном случае результат должен быть:

```
 123456:Ответ
 1234:Ответ-1008!
 1234567:Ответ-232!
```

---

Вроде бы двигаюсь в правильном направлении, но увы, не получается.

```
if (PosEx(':', stroka)=0) or (PosEx(';', stroka)=0) and (length(stroka) <3)
```

Comment: Вроде бы в неправильном, 
`if ( (length(stroka)-PosEx(':',stroka)<3))`, дальше сами.

Comment: в `123456:Ответ` после двоеточия целых 5 символов, почему его нет в результате?

Comment: @teran,Извините опечатка вышла. Уже исправил вопрос.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Сделал ответ на данный вопрос, благодаря Вам решил задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответил на вопрос благодаря пользователю - Владимир Клыков.

```
if (length(stroka)-PosEx(':',stroka) < 3) or (length(stroka)-PosEx(';',stroka) < 3) then
  break
else
```

---

А еще лучше не плодить отрицания и переписать if not ((A) or (B)) на if (not A) and (not B), т.е. будет:

```
if (length(stroka)-PosEx(':',stroka) >= 3) and (length(stroka)-PosEx(';',stroka) >= 3) then
```

Comment: чтобы не делать `break` можно записать условие как `if not (...) then ...;`

Comment: Так как данный ответ решил Вашу проблему - "ткните" галочку под стрелками "вниз-вверх" чтобы пометить ответ как окончательный. Это позволит будущим посетителям точно знать, что данное решение работоспособно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Dima этого, емнип, ТС не сможет сделать в течении 48 часов с момента ответа.